# Datatable multi search filter is not updated skipping table tabs

Tags: django, datatables, django-rest-framework

I am using Datatables with Django and rest_framework_datatables. 
The table is created with its search field that work perfectly.

I added the multi search filter too, but when I skip between the pagination links these filters **show always the same data** that are relative the first query (obviously the table show different data)

I would to show in these filters all the values at disposal for the relative column, otherwise upgrade them with the data that the table shows.

```
var table = $('reportsTable').DataTable({
    "ajax":         {
      'ajax': '/api/myreports/?format=datatables',
    },
    "columns":      [
        { "data": "id" },
        { "data": "title" },
        { "data": "subtitle" },
        { "data": "description" },
    ],
    initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns().every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select><option value="">All</option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {

                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );
            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
            } );
        }
 });
```